# Can an instance of object return its own value in c++?

Tags: c++, overloading, this, instance, operator-keyword

So I'm defining a variation on int as a rotating integer class which is very simple, but I want to be able to do something like

```
cout << x << '\n';
```

rather than :

```
cout << x.value() << '\n';
```

Is this at all possible?

Is there nothing like

```
    class rotating_int
{
private:
    int _value, _low, _high;
public:
    int operator++(int) { if (++_value > _high) _value = _low; return _value; }
    int operator--(int) { if (--_value < _low) _value = _high; return _value; }
    int operator++() { if (++_value > _high) _value = _low; return _value; }
    int operator--() { if (--_value < _low) _value = _high; return _value; }

    void operator=(int value) { _value = value;  }

    int operator==(int value) { return _value == value; }

    int val() { return _value; }
    rotating_int(int value, int low, int high) { _value = value; _low = low; _high = high; }

     int ^rotating_array() { return &_value; }

};
```

Where "^rotating_array" is much like the definition of a destructor ~rotating_array.

Seem to be a fundamental of object orientated design that it should be.

Comment: have you tried overloading operator << for your class? (or maybe an implicit conversion to int, but that's a less desirable solution)

Comment: Yes it is. Look up *operator overloading*.

Answer (score 4):

You should use ***operator overloading***.

Inside your class:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const RotatingInt& x)
{
    os << x.value;
    return os;
}
```

Change `RotatingInt` to your class name.

Here's an example: http://cpp.sh/9turd

Comment: I am using operator overloading but I want simply the using of instance x to return x.value() so I don't have to overload every possible operator to access the private member "_value".  Then all I have to overload is ++ and -- and cout << x; where x is the instance return it's private variable "_value" rather than overload << and >>. It's slightly annoying this seems not to be possible for trivial classes like this variation of "int".

Comment: I couldn't find any reference to what you're asking, I'm sorry. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: No it doesn't seem possible.  I've just written 20+ operator overloads ALL of which could be solved with something like "int& ^rotating_array() { return _value; }" in the same way a constructor or destructor is defined.  It's ANNOYING!  Thank you so much for your help.  Good to have the situation resolved either way.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, C++ has something extremely useful but it takes some effort to really understand it. As Borgleader indicates: you want to overload the << operator.

In your rotating integer class you need to tell the compiler that the operator<< (this is how the function is called which the compiler calls when it sees the << operator for any object) can access the private members of the class. This is done by making the function a friend function of the rotating integer class. In the class you add:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const RotatingInteger&)
```

The implementation of the operator<< function could look like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const RotatingInteger& i) {
    os << i.value;
    return os; // you need to return the stream in order to add something
               // else after you pass the RotatigInteger-object like in your 
               // example: cout << x << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I wanted and I am aware of operator overloading but the chaining of streams like that is certainly useful information.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, you could make your instance variable public but this is against the rules of OOP. Another option is to return the reference of the instance variable by making a member function like this: `int& getValue() {return _value;}` and then you could write `x.getValue()++` and it would increase the `_value` by one. But you will always have to call the getValue function. If you don't want that I'm afraid you have to overload all of the necessary operators.

Comment: Thanks, that was my depressing answer to - it would be nice to have something like   "int& rotating_array() { return &_value; }".  Oh well thank you for your help.  It's good to know definitively.